# PHP not receiving serialized data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Goal: Grab user-entered data from form, run validation through jquery, then post the variables to php script for storing data into a database.

Issue: Ajax request script is working and produces the serialized data; however, the PHP script returns an empty POST array.

JS Console Log: serialized data string is produced and contains variables from the form: x_first_name and x_last_name.

Error in PHP: Undefined index for all the POST variables.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="processsale.php" id="checkout_form" name="checkout_form">
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="x_first_name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input name="x_first_name" id="x_first_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control cc-owner" autocomplete="x_first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="x_last_name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
          <input name="x_last_name" id="x_last_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control" autocomplete="x_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

AJAX Snippet:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

   // Variable to hold request
      var request;


        $('#checkout_form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();


         // Abort any pending request
        if (request) {
            request.abort();
        }
        // setup some local variables
        var $form = $(this);

        // Let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        // Serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        // Fire off the request to processsale.php
        request = $.ajax({
            url: "processsale.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: serializedData
        });


        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            console.log(serializedData)
            window.location.replace("processsale.php")
        });
        return false;

     // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {
            // Reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        }); // end of form submit

    });

  }); //End of doc ready
  </script>
```

PHP (processsale.php) Snippet:

```
print_r($_POST);
echo $_POST['x_first_name'];
echo $_POST['x_last_name'];
```

Comment: Are you sure `this` is the form?

Comment: I'm using 'this' to refer to my form checkout_form.  That line is a subset of this code: ' $('#checkout_form').submit(function(e) {... '

Comment: Also - I know it works because the console correctly outputs the serializedData (which consists of user-entered data: x_first_name and x_last_name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! My mistake: I was trying to post the data twice.

Via my HTML form element:

```
<form method="post" action="processsale.php" id="checkout_form" name="checkout_form">
```

and also via ajax:

```
       e.preventDefault();
```

...

```
 request = $.ajax({
        url: "processsale.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  serializedData,
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data);
           }
    });

request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Log a message to the console
    console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    console.log(serializedData);
    //redirect to php script to process form data
    window.location.replace("processsale.php")
});
```

My js was ignoring my form method to post to my php (processsale.php). This is because `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default way of submitting forms (via HTML element `<form method="post"...`. However, it was successfully posting the form data via ajax, as verified by my `console.log(serializedData)`. Although the data was posted to my php script via ajax, the data did not transfer when I redirected to my php script via `window.location.replace("processsale.php")`.  That's because `window.location.replace` runs the php script, as if newly visited, without any of the posted data from ajax.

**SOLUTION**

I ran the form validation through jquery, and if it was successful, I submitted the form using my HTML `<form method="post" action="processsale.php">`. This way I avoided using the `window.location.replace("processsale.php")` because this was just opening the script without grabbing any of the posted form data.

However, if the form could not be validated via jquery, and it failed validation, I used `e.preventDefault();` to bypass the posting of data via the HTML element `<form ...` This prevents the posting of invalid form data to my php script.

This is what I added to my code. FYI:`text-success` was the output of a successful validation.

```
        //if jquery validation is successful
        if ($('.text-success').length){ 

                //send msg in console
                console.log("SUCCESS!");
                return true;

        //if jquery validation fails
        } else {

            console.log("Errors on page");

            //prevent from submitting form normally: via html form element
            e.preventDefault();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

are you using form on submit event ?

Javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkout_form").submit(function(){
            var $form = $(this);

```
    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    console.log(serializedData)

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData
    });

    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        console.log(serializedData)
        //window.location.replace("processsale.php")
    });
    return false;
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="processsale.php" id="checkout_form" name="checkout_form">
  <fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="x_first_name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
        <input name="x_first_name" id="x_first_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control cc-owner" autocomplete="x_first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="x_last_name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
          <input name="x_last_name" id="x_last_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control" autocomplete="x_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
    </div>

  </fieldset>
  <button type="submit" id="harchivemenus">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately it still doesn't work.  I, redirected to my php script and still get empty post arrays. I re-posted my js so you can see the full script. my output of the console log from my js script is as follows: x_first_name=John&x_last_name=Doe.  I just don't get why my processsale.php script `print_r($_POST)` is still empty.

Comment: if you are redirected to your php page than i am sure that you are not using  return false; in your javascript please check my code again

Answer (score 0):

Try this but i just create the post button when you click that button after filled the form you can get the entered value in your php file

```
function formsubmit(){
           //but when perform an event that time only you will get the post data

        // setup some local variables
       //In this use your form id here
        var $form = $('#checkout_form');

        // Let's select and cache all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        // Serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        request = $.ajax({
            url: "processsale.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  serializedData,
            success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
               }
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            console.log(serializedData)
            window.location.replace("processsale.php")
        });
 }
```

html file

```
        <form method="post" action="processsale.php" id="checkout_form" name="checkout_form">
          <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="x_first_name" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                <input name="x_first_name" id="x_first_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control cc-owner" autocomplete="x_first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="x_last_name" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                  <input name="x_last_name" id="x_last_name" type="text" class="input-lg form-control" autocomplete="x_last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
            </div>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
    <input type='button' value='post' onClick="formsubmit()"/>
```

Get post value in processsale.php file

```
<?php 

 //get post value from ajax
 if(isset($_POST)){

   print_r($_POST);
   echo $_POST['x_first_name'];
   echo $_POST['x_last_name'];

  }

?>
```

Comment: I tried this, but i have the same issue.  thank you for your help though.